# How do i concatenate information from a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

**i just realised i've worded this very poorly**
**i'm trying to find out if i can do this within an insert statement, not when trying to output the data**

This might sound very confusing but hopefully i can explain it.

I have two tables, `expertise` (parent) and `department` (child)

In expertise I have :

```
exp_id int(2) primary key 
exp_name varchar(30)
```

In department I have:

```
dep_id int(2) primary key  
dep_name varchar(30)  
exp_id int(2) foreign key
```

I DO NOT want the outcome for the department rows to look like this:

dep_id dep_name        exp_id

```
1    accounting       32
1    accounting       27
1    accounting       29
```

I WANT IT to look like this

```
dep_id dep_name      exp_id
1    accounting      32, 27, 29
```

So there is multiple rows within a row, if that makes any sense.

I believe its concatenation i have to work with, but I've never used this before and was looking for some help

**i just realised i've worded this very poorly**
**i'm trying to find out if i can do this within an insert statement, not when trying to output the data**

Comment: What is in what table. Like what is 32, an id?  What is 1

Comment: It would seem that dept is both an entity and an intersect table. Poorly normalized?

Comment: You really _dont_ want your department table to look like that. delimited fields are a terrible idea in almost every single circumstance in an rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use `group_concat`, ie:

```
select dep_id, dep_name, group_concat(exp_id) exp_id
  from department
  group by dep_id, dep_name
```

You should also consider normalisation your department table, it is currently violating first normal form due to the repeating groups of `dep_id, dep_name`. [reference here](http://rdbms.opengrass.net/2_Database%20Design/2.2_Normalisation/2.2.4_1NF%20Repeating%20Attributes.html)

**edit**

I see you updated your question to say you want the data stored in this way in the table, not displayed.

The answer to that is: you really don't.

delimited fields are all but impossible to deal with, and are just all around horrible in an rdbms. If you absolutely *must* have it this way, you could use the above query to create a view, and at least store the real data in a proper, normalised fashion.

To re-iterate. Please don't do this. Kittens will die.

Comment: Agreed. And they will slowly.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of normalized data

```
-- drop table expertise
create table expertise
(   expId int not null,
    expName varchar(100) not null
);
insert expertise (expId,expName) values (32,'number massaging');
insert expertise (expId,expName) values (27,'misrepresentation');
insert expertise (expId,expName) values (29,'embezzlement');

-- select * from expertise
-- drop table department;
create table department
(   deptId int not null,
    deptName varchar(100) not null
);
insert into department (deptId,deptName) values (1,'Accounting');
insert into department (deptId,deptName) values (2,'Executive');
insert into department (deptId,deptName) values (3,'Food Service');

-- select * from department

-- drop table expDeptIntersect;
create table expDeptIntersect 
(   expId int not null,
    deptId int not null
);
insert expDeptIntersect (expId,deptId) values (27,1);
insert expDeptIntersect (expId,deptId) values (32,1);
insert expDeptIntersect (expId,deptId) values (29,1);
--select * from expdeptintersect

select d.deptId,d.deptName,group_concat(i.expId) expId
from department d
join expDeptIntersect i
on i.deptId=d.deptId
group by d.deptId,d.deptName
```